# How do I make a phone number recognizable to a smartphone?

Tags: iphone, android, smartphone, cufon

I have a phone number on my contact page and I want it to dial when someone taps it on a smartphone browser, Android and iPhone. Can someone tell me how that's done? Thanks! BTW, I'm using Cufon which is not selectable. Is that a problem here?

Comment: I've seen references to: android:autoLink="all" but I don't know where to plug that in. Presumably, that won't work with an iPhone either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Android phones will pick up phone-number-looking numbers automatically (sometimes too aggressively - my DroidX insists that all 4-digit numbers are phone numbers, which is rather irritating), but I suppose the cufon might be messing with that.

If you want to be explicit, though, you can use an [RFC3966](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt) [telephone link](http://www.raizlabs.com/blog/202/iphone-telephone-hyperlinks), e.g.

```
<a href="tel:+1-800-275-2273">
Call Apple Customer Support at 1-800-275-2273
</a>.
```

You can also check out [Apple's docs on phone links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html).

Comment: Bingo! Thanks! Works on my Android, I assume it'll work on iPhone too.

Comment: But, how about making this so it's not a link?

Comment: You mean so it's not linked on non-mobile devices? Not sure there's a way to do that, short of letting the phone-number-autodetection for your platform kick in instead of using a link. Have you checked if that works with cufon off?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme to learn what a URI scheme is.

the tel URI scheme seems like what you need, but I have no idea if it really works or is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the now native phone number detection by using a simple tag:

Credit: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/phone-number-links/